# Confidence intervals for median from Wilcoxon signed rank statistic

Tags: confidence-interval, nonparametric, ranking, order-statistics, wilcoxon-signed-rank

We are given the sample $X_1, ..., X_n$ from a common distribution with median $\mu$. Using Wilcoxon's signed rank statistic, how can I construct a confidence interval in terms of the order statistics of the random samples here?

In particular, I am looking to show $(X_{(3)},X_{(10)})$ gives a 96.21% confidence interval for the median $\mu$ when $n=12$.

Comment: While $(X_{(3)},X_{(10)})$ might indeed constitute a CI for the median, it doesn't seem to be related to the signed rank statistic. If anything, it's connected to the *sign test*. Please clarify your question. How does the question arise?/Where do the specifics come from?

Comment: I thought the signed rank statistic was used in the sign test? What's the difference? Actually the question does say "by considering the critical values of the sign test ..." rather than how I have phased out above. But I do not see how this changes things. Thanks.

Comment: isn't it the Wilcoxon test used to compare the ranks of two samples?

Comment: a.e. [signed rank test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) vs [sign test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_test). The signed rank test multiplies the signs by the rank of the absolute values of the data (where the data are the pair-differences for the paired version). The sign test just uses the signs without regard to size. Perhaps you should fix your question. It's now clear you should also add the `self-study` tag and modify your question according to its [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)

Comment: @chuse There's more than one test named after Wilcoxon. The two-sample one is the *rank sum* test rather than the signed rank test. He wrote about both in a single paper in 1945.